# Conditional join multiple tables overwriting instead of making new columns

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have three data frames that I am trying to join.  The difficulty is that I want conflicting values in the same column to be replaced instead of creating a new row.  I have tried different variations of left_join and full_join followed by filter.

Example Data Frames:

```
df.0 <- 
 ID SEQUENCE    FIXDT.0 FIXU.0           SEX
  3        0 2010-08-01        Spayed Female
  1        0 2011-10-01        Neutered Male
  2        0                1  Spayed Female
  5        0 2012-05-01        Neutered Male

df.1_2 <- 
 ID SEQUENCE    FIXDT.0 FIXU.0           SEX
  3        1 2010-10-01        Spayed Female
  1        1                1  Neutered Male
  4        2                1  Spayed Female
  5        1 2012-05-01        Neutered Male

df.3_6 <-
 ID SEQUENCE    FIXDT.0 FIXU.0           SEX
  6        3 2011-08-01        Neutered Male
  1        6 2012-10-01        Neutered Male
  4        4 2010-02-01        Spayed Female
  5        3 2012-05-01        Neutered Male

df.cohort <-
 ID    SEX.STATUS   BIRTH.DATE  ENROLLED.DATE
  1  Neutered Male  8/23/2010    12/11/2012
  2  Spayed Female  6/16/2011     9/11/2013
  3  Spayed Female  9/28/2011      9/6/2013 
  4  Spayed Female  6/26/2011      1/2/2013
  5  Neutered Male  4/15/2011      7/5/2012
  6  Neutered Male  5/12/2010     8/16/2011
  7  Intact Male    2/17/2011    10/25/2012
```

I want to join these together with the desired output below.  The idea would be that I am joining them together and replacing previous values with values from the next table joined. The other important thing to note is that I want a date for FIXDT in the output if possible.  This would mean replacing for some rows but not for others

```
df.full <-
 ID    SEX.STATUS   BIRTH.DATE  ENROLLED.DATE            Sex   FIXDT       FIXU  SEQUENCE
  1  Neutered Male  8/23/2010    12/11/2012    Neutered Male   2011-10-01              0
  2  Spayed Female  6/16/2011     9/11/2013    Spayed Female                 1         0
  3  Spayed Female  9/28/2011      9/6/2013    Spayed Female   2010-08-01              0
  4  Spayed Female  6/26/2011      1/2/2013    Spayed Female   2010-02-01              4
  5  Neutered Male  4/15/2011      7/5/2012    Neutered Male   2012-05-01              0
  6  Neutered Male  5/12/2010     8/16/2011    Neutered Male   2011-08-01              3
  7  Intact Male    2/17/2011    10/25/2012
```

I know this make require some intermediate data.frames and have tried to work around it that way some too.  I tried using `dplyr` and `filter` but realized those are best for equal joins and I am trying to do an unequal join.

Comment: are you looking to join only by `ID` ?

Answer (score 0):

For the your join question this should do the trick. This implies that you want to do a full replacement of shared columns, which seems to be what you are looking for

```r
library('dplyr')

special_join <- function(x, y, by, ...) {

    shared_cols <- colnames(x) [colnames(x) %in% colnames(y) & !colnames(x) %in% by]
    x[,shared_cols] <- NULL                                                                                                        

    full_join(x, y, by, ...)

}

a <- data.frame(ID = 1:4, variable=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), other_variable=4:7)                                                      
b <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, variable=c('z', 'x', 'y'))

special_join(a, b, by='ID')
#   ID other_variable variable                                                                                                       
# 1  1              4        z                                                                                                     
# 2  2              5        x
# 3  3              6        y                                                                                                      
# 4  4              7     <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the code in the answer above after some more data cleaning.  However what ended up working best was a step wise answer.

1) Merge each df with the cohort, then subset to keep only one dog using distinct.  For example with the df.1_2:

```
df.1_2_join <- left_join(df.1_2, cohort, by="DOGID")
df.1_2_join <- df.1_2_join[order(df.1_2_join$SEQUENCE),]
df.1_2_join <- df.1_2_join %>% distinct(DOGID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

2)change so all corresponding column names match.

3)do a `full_join` by all columns

4) order the full data.frame by Sequence and use distinct again to remove duplicated ID's

In the process I also learned that `duplicated2` is a helpful function to write a list of all the duplicated rows in a dataframe, not just their 2,3 or more appearances.  I used this to check and make sure that all ID's were not duplicated and had the correct info.